# How to Copy and Rename multiple files using shell

Tags: shell

I want to copy only `20180721` files from `Outgoing` to `Incoming` folder. I also want to **remove the first numbers** from the file name and want to **rename from -1 to -3**. I want to keep my commands to minimum so I am using `pax` command below.

Filename:

```
216118105741_MOM-09330-20180721_102408-1.jar
```

Output expected:

```
MOM-09330-20180721_102408-3.jar
```

I have tried this command and it's doing most of the work apart from removing the number coming in front of the file name. Can anyone help?

Command used:

```
pax -rw -pe -s/-1/-3/ ./*20180721*.jar ../Incoming/
```

Comment: Does anyone know how can i use the above pax command to just remove the first  digits and _  coming in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple script using just [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for file in *20180721*.jar; do
    new=${file#*_}
    cp -- "$file" "/path/to/destination/${new%-*}-3.jar"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

In general

```
for i in `ls files-to-copy-*`; do 
   cp $i `echo $i | sed "s/rename-from/rename-to/g"`; 
done;
```

In your case

```
for i in `ls *_MOM*`; do 
   cp $i `echo $i | sed "s/_MOM/MOM/g" | sed "s/-1/-3/g"`; 
done;
```

Comment: Its not just one file but multiple files, the above command will take care of just one file

Comment: No it will take care of all the files with filename starting with 216118105741

Comment: no the starting number is not constant so it wouldn't work.

Comment: It still fails 3 conditions, only 20180721 and should start with MOM and should be copied from Outgoing to Incoming folder. I fixed first two but still working on copying to Incoming folder

`for i in `ls **20180721*`; do cp $i `echo $i | sed "s/^[0-9]*_MOM/MOM/g" | sed "s/-1/-3/g"`; done`

Answer (score 0):

`pax` only applies the first successful substitution even if the `-s` option is specified more than once. You can pipe the output to a second pax instance, though.

```
pax -w -s ':^[^_]*_::p' *20180721*.jar | (builtin cd ../Incoming; pax -r -s ':1[.]jar$:3.jar:p')
```